# Is there any fast and easy way to store the state of a (flask + webhook) Telegram bot?

Tags: flask, pythonanywhere, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, telepot

I'm writing a Telegram bot in a Flask web app (with webhook and telepot), and I've been searching for an easy way of having just a little of data persistency (storing a bunch of variables so that the bot remembers which level of a text-based puzzle game I'm in).

I've previously failed at writing files using Flask (see previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56889594/whats-the-structure-of-telegrams-updates-to-webhook-flask-app)), and other solutions like creating an SQL database (or any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815451/are-global-variables-thread-safe-in-flask-how-do-i-share-data-between-requests)) feel like a lot of new stuff just for a couple of variables.

There has to be an easier way... (hey, I found a cool one, please let me post the answer!)

Comment: Just wanted to share a cool weird but really easy way of doing it I found (by using the channel's description as a variable), but the question was closed before I could write the answer.

I guess I was too slow at answering my own question.

Comment: Well just made another (hope that better explained) question and answered it there instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56933499/can-i-store-bot-state-data-on-the-involved-telegram-chat-itself/56933503#56933503