# Can I store bot state data on the involved telegram chat itself?

Tags: flask, telegram, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, telepot

I'm trying to store a bit of data regarding the bot's conversation within a group (i.e. the bot manages kind of a text-based chat scape room and I want to save which "world" and "stage" the group is in at the time), and so I was wondering whether you can just store this little amount of data within the chat itself (instead of saving it on the bot server side*, which seems [quite a lot of work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815451/are-global-variables-thread-safe-in-flask-how-do-i-share-data-between-requests) for something that should be so simple).

So following this python zen philosophy, I'm trying to find a KISS way of storing that couple of values, maybe within the telegram chat itself, so that I don't need to manage any serious database on the server side in order to classify which chat things came from.

*I'm using telepot with webhook in a Flask web app.

Comment: Just to update on it a bit. I've been using the solution I proposed down below, and it's working like charm. I've been saving four one-digit variables, and two arrays of boolean values like so: `" (❌):1-0-3:10010-001100:0"` , and retrieving it at the beginning of the bot's code by `.split(":")` and then `.split("-")`. 

If you prepare yourself a couple of functions to build and parse it it's really easy to use and Telegram goes clean and fast at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... I just wanted to share that I found a deeply ridiculous but quite effective way of doing it (as long as you don't need to store private data in there, and with the condition that only the bot -and not the players- can mess with the chat's description).

Bots can check and change the chat's description via the commands `bot.getChat("@group_id")` and `.setChatDescription("@group_id","New desc")` so you actually can save there a string that contains all the values you need, and retrieve them later.

In the case exposed, I could save the current game level in the description, like `"Level: 4"`, and retrieve it at any time by:

```
desc = bot.getChat("@my_game_chat")["description"]
level = desc[7:]
```

And in this case it works as a clue for the player too.

Using a similar approach you could save different stuff there at the same time, even maybe obscuring it a bit by just putting it as a string of numbers with no labels `"01-21-5493"`

```
desc = bot.getChat("@my_game_chat")["description"]
world, stage, score = desc.split('-')
```

Also if you work with fixed width numbers, you could even throw in there some random numbers in irrelevant places so as to confuse any possible gossip.

PS: `bot.getChat()` returns a structure like this (that's why we need `["description"]`):

```py
{
'id': -2424242424242, 
'title': 'Channel Name', 
'username': 'channelusername', 
'type': 'channel', 
'description': 'Pernils i tal'
}
```